# How can I force a specific view to be landscape using the Ionic Framework

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, orientation

I have an app that is forced portrait in `config.xml` but I want a specific view in the app to be displayed as landscape. What would be the best way to achieve this? Is there an option already within the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/)?

I have tried setting the view controller to rotate the page container element by 90deg via CSS but this is a bad hack since the OS doesn't know that the device should be rotated and thus the status bar/OS nav items won't rotate.

Is there a way to force specific views to a specified orientation when using the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/)?

Comment: Good question. However, as far as I know it's not possible in Ionic framework, but if someone knows the solution please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like [this](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) plugin will help you.

For landscape, you have to use `screen.lockOrientation('landscape');` in the controller.

And on other pages, if they are not in portrait view you have to put `screen.lockOrientation('portrait');`

Answer (score 0):

for Ionic 2.x there is ionic native plugin can be used.

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) { }

...


// get current
console.log(this.screenOrientation.type); // logs the current orientation, example: 'landscape'

// set to landscape
this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);

// allow user rotate
this.screenOrientation.unlock();

// detect orientation changes
this.screenOrientation.onChange().subscribe(
   () => {
       console.log("Orientation Changed");
   }
);
```

see [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation/).